# Create a File or Directory as User in the CommonAppData Location with .NET

Tags: .net, uac

I need to create a file/directory in the common application data folder that will be shared across all accounts.  If I create the file/directory as admin, I have no problem but if I create the file/directory as a user the file/directory goes into the virtualized folder for the user's account.  Has anyone found a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install your app can't you create a directory to use for the other users.  Or is that not a valid scenario.

Comment: Do newly created files in that directory inherit those permissions?